# remove a random entry from HashMap in rust

Tags: rust

I would like to remove a random element from a `HashMap`. However, I kept getting this error.

```
error[E0502]: cannot borrow `self.map` as mutable because it is also borrowed as immutable
  --> src/main.rs:23:9
   |
21 |         let key_to_delete = self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap();
   |                             -------- immutable borrow occurs here
22 |         println!("key_to_delete: {:?}", key_to_delete);
23 |         self.map.remove(&key_to_delete);
   |         ^^^^^^^^^------^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
   |         |        |
   |         |        immutable borrow later used by call
   |         mutable borrow occurs here

error: aborting due to previous error

For more information about this error, try `rustc --explain E0502`.
```

However, if I add a `.clone()` at the end of that line, the error is gone. While I fixed this problem (mostly by trials and errors), I still don't understand why it works. Specifically, why does this error showed up in the first place? Shouldn't the immutable reference to `self.map` get dropped after the line

```rust
let key_to_delete = self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap()
```

finish executing?
In this example, the key is of type `i32`, which only takes 4 byte. Therefore, it's OK to clone. But what if the key is some large struct or `clone` is not desirable for other reasons? How then should I solve this problem?

Another observation is that my IDE (Intellij with rust plugin) showed that the type of `key_to_delete` is `&i32` if I don't have `.clone()` and `i32` if I do. I am not sure if this matters.

Any clarification is appreciated.

Here is my code.

```rust
use std::collections::HashMap;
use rand::{Rng, thread_rng};

#[derive(Debug)]
struct MyStruct {
    map: HashMap<i32, i32>,
}

impl MyStruct {
    fn new() -> Self {
        MyStruct { map: HashMap::new() }
    }

    fn add(&mut self, key: i32, value: i32) {
        self.map.insert(key, value);
        println!("after add: {:?}", self.map);
    }

    fn delete(&mut self) {
        let x: usize = thread_rng().gen_range(0..self.map.len());
        let key_to_delete = self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap().clone(); // this "clone" is critical
        println!("key_to_delete: {:?}", key_to_delete);
        self.map.remove(&key_to_delete);
        println!("map after delete: {:?}", self.map);
    }
}

fn main() {
    let mut c = MyStruct::new();
    c.add(1, 2);
    c.add(3, 4);
    c.add(5, 6);
    c.delete();
}
```

Comment: `keys()` return an iterator over `&K`

Comment: The problem is that you get a reference to the key which resides in (i.e. is owned by) the hashmap, which is why you get `&i32`. If Rust allowed you to modify the hashmap while holding on to that reference, the reference would get invalidated. There is currently no better way to do what you want than to clone the key.

Answer (score 2):

When you call `self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap()` you don't get a key - you get *a reference* to a key.

Rust guarantees that this reference stays valid for as long as it lives - that's the whole idea behind Rust's borrow checker and memory safety in general. In our case, this it means that Rust guarantees that the key *inside the map (alongside the associated value)* will be present in the map as long as your *reference* to the key lives.

But the way the Rust compiler enforces it is rather brutal - it just disallows you to change the state of the map *in any way* as long as your *reference* to the key lives. Unfortunately, as a result, you cannot use your reference to remove its corresponding entry from the map.

To illustrate this point, let's look at a slightly modified version of your code:

```rust
fn delete(&mut self) { //not really a delete at this point
    let x: usize = thread_rng().gen_range(0..self.map.len());
    let key_to_delete = self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap(); // this "clone" is gone
    self.map.insert(123, 456); // <- this will cause a compiler error
    println!("key_to_delete: {:?}", key_to_delete);
    // self.map.insert(123, 456);  // <- this will not cause a compiler error as the reference to the key no longer exists
    println!("map after delete: {:?}", self.map);
}
```

Here I've changed the `remove` to `insert` so that we **know** we aren't risking that our key might be deleted. And yet the code doesn't compile for exactly the same reason as you originally reported.

Comment: I'm learning rust and I understood it a little better from fygesser. The key is to understand that `key_to_delete` is of type `&i32`. It reads "this is a reference to an i32". And, then, everything they say is applied. The compiler won't let you mess with references. Another option to `.clone` is the [dereference operator](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/expressions/operator-expr.html#the-dereference-operator): `let key_to_delete = *self.map.keys().skip(x).next().unwrap();`, which will then assign the value of the &reference to the variable, so you aren't relying on the ref anymore.

Comment: I see, correct me if I am wrong. If a reference to any field of a struct is active, there is an active reference to the struct. Because a reference to key is part of the `HashMap`, it count it as an active immutable reference to the `HashMap`, so I cannot create an active mutable reference to call the `remove` method.

Comment: @lewisxy Yes that's correct

Comment: @GabrielVilchesAlves, it doesn't work unless the key type implements `Copy` trait. Of course, to make the `.clone()` work it need to implement `Clone` trait. Most of the times, it's enough to implement automatically by using `derive`.

Comment: @fygesser, thanks. Are there ways to make it compile without copying/cloning the key? I know copying the HashMap key usually isn't a problem. I just want to make sure I can deal with it in other situations where `clone` isn't an option.

Answer (score 1):

It’s at least possible to remove an arbitrary entry from a `HashMap` whose keys don’t implement `Clone`, in a somewhat roundabout way, on current Nightly using the experimental [`hash_raw_entry` feature](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/collections/struct.HashMap.html#method.raw_entry_mut):

```rust
#![feature(build_hasher_simple_hash_one)]
#![feature(hash_raw_entry)]

use std::collections::hash_map::{HashMap, RawEntryMut};
use std::hash::{BuildHasher, Hash};

fn pop<K: Hash, V>(m: &mut HashMap<K, V>) -> Option<(K, V)> {
    let hash = m.hasher().hash_one(m.keys().next()?);

    match m.raw_entry_mut().from_hash(hash, |_| true) {
        RawEntryMut::Occupied(entry) => Some(entry.remove_entry()),
        RawEntryMut::Vacant(_) => unreachable!("no entry with hash of first key"),
    }
}
```